# In SSIS toolbox I dont have ODBC destination with 'planet' like symbol

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, odbc, etl, ssis-2017

I have visual studio 2017 enterprise 15.9.5 with installed: Developer Extensions for Visual Studio 2017, Productivity power tools 2017, SSDT component. In SSIS Toolbox my ODBC destination icon is

[image]

System reinstallation didn't fix this problem.

All guys from my team have this 'planet' in ODBC destination, and I am only one with error:

> Error at Insert Data to Hana [ODBC Destination [59]]: SQLSTATE: S1000, Message: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;260 invalid column name: VALUE: line 1 col 135 (at pos 134);

*Screenshot*

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Is the functionality broken? Or are you just not liking the icon you're seeing?

Comment: Yeah, looks like the same icon I have in VS 2017. You tagged SAP, is there an extension you might have missed on that end?